# Node.js and axios : How to return response after asynchronous request to another server?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to node.js and from the postman I'm making a post call to my node server which further makes a call to remote server. I'm using axios to make the call, the api is return something like this :

```
exports.fetchFromRemoteServer = function(req, res, next){
  const query = req.query;

  axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'http://www.someUrl.com',
        params: query
      }).then(function(response){
        console.log(response);
        res.send('data', response);
      }).catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

Whenever I'm making this call, I get the data on the node server but I don't know how to make that async so that whenever it comes in the `.then` of the api call `res.send` start working. The postman keep showing me the loading state.

Comment: "The postman keep showing me the loading state.". Probably because the request fails, and it goes into the catch block, which does not return any response. Try sending a 400 response in the catch block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution to this using the [async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) module and the solution looked like :

```
exports.fetchFromRemoteServer = function(req, res, next){
  const query = req.query;

async.parallel([
 function(callback){
   axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: 'http://www.someUrl.com',
      params: query
    }).then(function(response){
      callback(false, response);
    });
}],function(error, result){
   res.json(result[0].data.results);
 }); 
}
```

Comment: Is it right to run the two functions in parrallel? I believe his code needed some thing in waterfall or series. The result of the first function is important for the second.